# 'moment is not defined' error - due to upgrade to node v6.10.2?

Tags: node.js, momentjs

I recently upgrade my node..js function to v6.10.2 and suddenly my use of 'moment' has stopped working and I get the above error. I have not changed the code in the file that is throwing the error at all. Code snippet is:

```
                <div class="col-md-4 date">
                     <%= moment(comment.created).fromNow()%>
                </div>
```

And I require moment in both my app.js and my route file which accesses this page as follow:

```
moment                  =       require("moment"),
```

Is this a version issue?

UPDATE:

Here is my comment create route (which should generate the 'moment'):

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router({mergeParams: true});
var Blog = require("../models/blog");
var Comment = require("../models/comment");
var middleware = require("../middleware");
var moment = require('moment');
    Blog.findById(req.params.id, function(err, blog){
    if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.redirect("/blogs");
    } else {
        // create new comment
        Comment.create(req.body.comment, function(err, comment){
            if(err) {
                req.flash("error", "Something went wrong");
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                comment.author.id = req.user._id;
                comment.author.username = req.user.username;
                comment.author.image = req.user.image;
                comment.save();
                // connect new comment to campground
                blog.comments.push(comment);
                blog.save();
                var commentCreated = moment(comment.created).fromNow();
                if(req.xhr){
                    res.json({comment: comment, commentCreated: commentCreated, blog: blog});
                } else {
                //     // redirect to campground show page
                    req.flash("success", "Successfully added comment");
                    res.redirect("/blogs/" + blog._id);
                }
            }
        });
    }
});
});
```

And here is the template which should display the comment:

```
<!--================== COMMENTS DISPLAY SECTION ====================================================================-->
<div id="comments">
    <% blog.comments.forEach(function(comment){ %>
    <div class="comment-container">
        <div class="jumbotron comment">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-1">
                    <img class="comment-ico" src = "   <%=comment.author.image%>">
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-7">
                    <h4><%=comment.author.username%></h4>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 date">
                     <%= moment(comment.created).fromNow()%>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
            <div><p><%=comment.text%></p></div>
```

Here's the create comment form:

```
<div class = "container form">
   <form action = "/blogs/<%= blog._id %>/comments" method = "POST" id="newComment">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <img class="newComment-ico" src = "<%=currentUser.image%>">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <label for="comment">Add comment</label>
        </div>
    </div>
        <textarea class = "form-control" rows="4" placeholder = "Type comment here..." name = "comment[text]"></textarea>
        <button class = "btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>

<% } %>
```

Comment: It is not a version issue

Comment: Ok so any idea what might be happening here? It was working perfectly

Comment: you haven't provided enough information to answer this question. Post the relevant build code, configuration, and source code

Comment: no worries @Andy Ray, just added it into the original post

Comment: There might be an issue with node in general - are you on OS X and had node previous installed with homebrew ? Could be permission error... Try to  npm reinstall moment or npm i other modules and watch for error messages. When I did that update TypeScript stopped working but it had nothing to do with TS, see last comment in https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/issues/1228